# Looking to use delegateToSchema in nestjs resolver

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, nestjs

I have a local schema and a remote schema.
The local schema contains a subset of the remote schema and should proxy these to the remote graphql server.

Normally i would use something like:

```
public async getCar(
  obj: any,
  args: any,
  context: any,
  info: any
): Promise<Car> {
  return info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema({
    args: {
      id: context.userId,
    },
    context: {},
    fieldName: 'car',
    info,
    operation: 'query',
    schema: carExecutableSchema,
    transforms: [],
  });
}
```

but the `mergeInfo` is not available on the `info` field.

To get the remote schema I'm using:

```
const fetchRemoteSchema = async (): Promise<GraphQLSchema> => {
  const http = new HttpLink({
    fetch: nodeFetch,
    uri: process.env.CAR_GRAPHQL_URL,
  });

  const link = setContext((request, previousContext) => ({
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${process.env.CAR_BASIC_AUTH_TOKEN}`,
    },
  })).concat(http);

  const carSchema = await introspectSchema(link);

  const executableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    link,
    schema: carSchema,
  });
  return executableSchema;
};
```

and i use this in the module to initialize graphql

```
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [CarModule],
    inject: [CarService],
    useFactory: (mainAppService: MainAppService) => ({
      context: async ({ req }) => {
        return {
          userId: 1
        };
      },
      definitions: {
        outputAs: 'interface',
        path: '../../myschema.gql',
      },
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    }),
  }),
```

How could i make `mergeInfo` available? Or is there an easier way to delegate a graphql request?

Answer (score 0):

`info.mergeInfo` is only available when your schema is created with `mergeSchemas([])`. You can import `delegateToSchema` as function though: `import { delegateToSchema } from "apollo-server-express";`